# Internet connection in server inside a DMZ

Tags: linux, debian, routing, network-interface

my scenario is the following:

I have a server with a site in Drupal that is inside the DMZ. Because the server is located in this network it has no internet access but I need it for updating and maintenance tasks. In this server I have two network interfaces>

```
eth0> (for internet access)
address: 172.20.62.22
netmask: 255.255.0.0
gateway: 172.20.127.1

eth1> (for DMZ)
address: 10.0.1.41
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 10.0.1.1
```

So far what I have tried is create two routing tables (one for each interface) and set the default gateway to the interface with internet connection. My interfaces file contains the following:

```
auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 172.20.62.22
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  gateway 172.20.127.1
  post-up ip route add 172.20.0.0/16 dev eth0 table eth0table
  post-up ip route add default via 172.20.127.1 table eth0table
  post-up ip rule add from 172.20.62.22/32 table eth0table priority 100
  post-up ip route flush cache
  pre-down ip rule del from 172.20.62.22/32 table eth0table priority 100
  pre-down ip route flush table eth0table
  pre-down ip route flush cache

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 10.0.1.41
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  post-up ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0 table eth1table
  post-up ip route add default via 10.0.1.1 table eth1table
  post-up ip rule add from 10.0.1.41/32 table eth1table priority 110
  post-up ip route flush cache
  pre-down ip rule del from 10.0.1.41/32 table eth1table priority 110
  pre-down ip route flush table eth1table
  pre-down ip route flush cache
```

So far, I can establish an ssh connection with the two IPs (what makes me think that I'm on the right way) but inside the machine, I have internet access but cannot ping the other machines in the cluster that are in the same network (10.0.1.0/24). I think I'm close but I know there's something missing in the routing configuration. My biggest concerns are:

1. Should I have the interface to internet access in eth0 rather than in eth1 and let the DMZ interface be the first card?
2. Should I establish one routing table per interface or with just one the scenario can be accomplished?
3. The internet access in the machines inside DMZ are temporary (due to security policies in the organization) and once the maintenance is done, the internet access must be removed. Can this be done from the interfaces file just by doing "down" to the corresponding interface or should the interface be physically removed from the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The concept of DMZ is not having two NICs per server. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/DMZ_network_diagram_1_firewall.svg

Comment: So in that case I have this server inside the private network without internet access (lets say only the interface with the 10.0...), how could I get internet connection without a second card (like a bridge or something similar) just for a moment to update the site, repositories and packages? Sorry but I'm new in this topic

Comment: Either a public addresses in the DMZ, or more commonly, doing NAT to the private netlock space of the DMZ.